# Bug with HTML/PHP syntax highlighting

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 6.0.3. Max for 6.x.

There's a random bug with syntax highlighting when PHP is inside HTML:

[image]

On some lines it works, on some it doesn't...

Text code for Copy/Paste:

```
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135"
             alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
    </a>
<?php if ($is_packs) { ?>
    <div class="pictos">
        <?php
          if ($_product->getAttributeText('heure_conso'))
            echo '<div class="heure-conso">'.$_product->getAttributeText('heure_conso').'</div>';
          if ($_product->getAttributeText('pack_spec'))
            echo '<div class="pack_spec">'.$_product->getAttributeText('pack_spec').'</div>';
          echo '<div class="nb-plats">'.$_product->getAttributeText('pack_spec').'</div>';
          if (Mage::helper('tbm/data')->productIsOkForCustomerPhase($_product))
            echo '<div class="phase-ok">'.$this->__('Adapté à votre phase').'</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <?php echo $_product->getShortDescription() ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you add the source along with the image so that someone could try it out to check if there's an issue with the code or your highlighter?

Comment: Add it to the [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)

Comment: Where is the bug exactly? -- I see none so far -- colloring is done accordingly to your (weird?) settings.

Comment: @LazyOne Can't you see the image ?

Comment: I see the image -- I just do not see a bug. Are you talking about that light green background? If yes -- it's your settings and not a bug (but yes -- from your point of view it could be treated as bug if you do not remember how you have configured that).

Comment: @LazyOne No, I'm talking about those 7 PHP lines in the middle of the image which have no color at all, where as others (like `<?php if ($is_packs) { ?>` have colors.

Comment: Yes-- the lines on **light green background** -- right?

Comment: Yes, those lines, but that light green background is not the problem. Only the lack of coloring on the same lines, which is maybe related...

Comment: You will be surprised....

Comment: Well, are you thinking of a particular setting that may cause that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not a bug -- it's your custom settings.**

For whatever reason / somehow (does not actually matter) you have injected custom language (most likely HTML) into all DIV tags (the light green background). Now everything in such tags is forcibly treated as that language (HTML?) -- PHP is ignored completely.

`Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Language Injections` -- find and delete offending rule. It should have "project" or "global" in most right column (Scope) -- do not touch "bundled" ones.

Alternatively -- <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while having caret inside problematic place and choose "Uninject xxx" from popup menu.

Comment: All right, it was an injection for Derby language (??) that was applied to all files... I didn't do that, probably some WTF plugin... Thanks!